# Enigma having to do with bricks

Tags: abstract-algebra

A professor told us this one but I can't remember much of it, I hope you can help me find it.

This is what I remember, you have bricks, each brick has only (or at least) a side which length is an integer ($10cm$ for example) the rest are not (or the inverse), show that you can never have a straight wall (never mind the depth, imagine it in $2D$), at least a side must be larger than the other, or, show that you can't have a wall with integer side lengths.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Are we assuming the bricks are in the shapes of rectangles? So that $2$ sides are non-integer length while the remaining $2$ sides are integer length?

Comment: The bricks are assumed to be rectangles yes. Note that I am not asking help to solve the enigma, rather I'm trying to find help remembering it.

Comment: Explain better please

Comment: Check the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are thinking of the Rectangle Tiling Theorem:

> If a finite number of rectangles, every one of which has at least one integer side, perfectly tile a big rectangle, then the big rectangle also has at least one integer side.

You can find some nice proofs [on this site](http://www.inference.org.uk/mackay/rectangles/).

Comment: This is most likely it, thank you!